# Check exact word in scrabble words list

Tags: java, android

I have a Scrabble Clock with a verification tool inside.
The verification word space looks in green or red if the word that I check is in the list.

The thing is, if I use `sbuffer.toString().contains`, and write a word like `ABA`, the word space looks in green though `ABA` is not in the list, but `ABAC`, `ABACA` are in the list.

I would like to know how I can implement a condition in my code to check the exact complete word.

I've researched regex, boundary and matches, but I couldn't find a line code that words in my code.

Here is my code until now.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    TextView textInV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.texto_1);
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        textInV = findViewById(R.id.textIn);

        String data = "";
        StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();

        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fruits);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(is)));

        if (is != null)
        {
            try
            {
                while((data =reader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    sbuffer.append((data + "\n"));
                }

                is.close();

            }
            catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        textView.setText(sbuffer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ashutosh KS has already mentioned, `String.contains` is not really what you are looking for in this case: You want to check if two strings are identical, not if one *contains* the other.

The Java [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class contains a few methods that you can use to compare the content of two strings, of which you can choose accordingly to match your exact use case:

1. `contentEquals(CharSequence cs)` and `contentEquals(StringBuffer sb)` both check if the passed string representation's content matches the current one.
2. `equals(Object str)` is similar to `contentEquals` in that it makes an exact comparison between both strings, however it also checks to make sure that the passed object is in fact a string.
3. `equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString)`, as the name implies, will do a check while ignoring the string case.

These are the 'proper' ways to compare two strings exposed by the native API, so while it is absolutely possible to use other methods, it is a good idea to stick to these.

Answer (score 2):

The [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) method on a string tests whether the target is contained *as a substring*; if `ABAC` is contained as a substring then so is `ABA`, since `ABA` is a substring of `ABAC` and hence it is also a substring of any string which `ABAC` is a substring of. Therefore, it is not logically possible for the `String.contains` method to return `true` for `ABAC` and `false` for `ABA`.

You want to test if the target is *one of the elements of a collection of strings*, so you should use [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) on a collection of strings, not on a string. The best choice is a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), since this performs membership tests in O(1) time on average.

```java
> import java.util.*;
> Set<String> allowed = new HashSet<>();
> allowed.add("ABAC");
> allowed.add("ABACA");
> allowed.contains("ABA")
false
> allowed.contains("ABAC")
true
```

Comment: There are ~171,000 words in the English language, so while it's definitely a good idea to use a data structure with O(1) access, it's not strictly necessary here.

Comment: That depends how many words you want to check. If you're writing a Scrabble AI which tries to maximise its score by trying many possible options, then O(*n*) membership tests will probably not be good enough. But regardless of time complexity, the point is that substring containment is logically the wrong thing to check for.

Comment: To play devils advocate, if you wanted the best performance while searching (as an AI might do), it would make more sense to use a tree structure, where each branch is the next letter in a word.

Comment: Yes in a Scrabble check words, there are thousands of words. So...how can i input a .txt ina hashset to check the word...?

Comment: You open the file, read the words, and insert each word into the HashSet instead of writing them to a StringBuffer. Even if you have 200,000 words, it will still only take a few megabytes of memory.

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuffer`'s `contains()` check if the given string is a substring of the text in the `sbuffer`. That means, it will output `true` for searching "ABC" in "**ABC**", "**ABC**BC", "Z**ABC**", "Z**ABC**BC"...

If you want to search for a complete word in the `sbuffer`, then you can look for `"\n" + "ABC" + "\n"` since you're adding "\n" when adding words to `sbuffer`: `sbuffer.append((data + "\n"));`. But, you must also initialize `sbuffer` with "\n": `StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer("\n");`.

```java
sbuffer.toString().contains("\n" + "ABC" + "\n"); // this will do the trick
```

Test code:

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer("\n");
    StringBuffer sbuffer2 = new StringBuffer("\n");

    sbuffer.append("ABC" + "\n");
    sbuffer.append("ABCBC" + "\n");
    sbuffer.append("ZABC" + "\n");
    sbuffer.append("ZABCBC" + "\n");

    System.out.println("Is ABC in sbuffer = " + sbuffer.toString().contains("\n" + "ABC" + "\n"));

    sbuffer2.append("ABCBC" + "\n");
    sbuffer2.append("ZABC" + "\n");
    sbuffer2.append("ZABCBC" + "\n");

    System.out.println("Is ABC in sbuffer2 = " + sbuffer2.toString().contains("\n" + "ABC" + "\n"));
  }
}
```

Test output:

```
Is ABC in sbuffer = true
Is ABC in sbuffer2 = false
```

Comment: This way, works, but only with the first word of the list.

Comment: @ddaudiosolutions It works for every word - if it's first, in the middle, or the last word in the list. Are you following my example correctly? That is, adding "\n" to StringBuffer on initialization, adding "\n" with every insert, and checking for "\n" + WORD + "\n". I just tested it: https://repl.it/repls/FluidCraftyCells

Answer (score 0):

Now i have this, and works, but i have a file with the words, and i would like to add the files in the diccionario.

But i don't know how to read the file. I have try bufferread, but i need try/catch, and not works....

Some other solutions....

Thanks

```
boton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

           String content;
           @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
           @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                HashSet<String> diccionario = new HashSet<String>();
                //Adding elements to HashSet
                diccionario.add("CASA");
                diccionario.add("ABAC");

                if(diccionario.contains(textIn.getText().toString().toUpperCase()))
                {
                    textIn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else
                {
                    textIn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }

            }
```